# Iterate through array from Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to iterate through an array retrieved from Cloud Firestore. The array is a field in a document in the collection 'arbeidsokter'. To retrieve the data, I use the following code.

```
this.afd.collection<Items>('arbeidsokter').doc(this.planNext[0]["ID"])
      .valueChanges()
      .forEach((data) => oldTimestamps.push(data["Stempletider"]));

console.log(oldTimestamps);
```

This gives me an array, but the length of it is zero, even though it looks like the timestamps have been pushed to it ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXmpD.png)). How can I access the timestamps within the array?

**EDIT:** [Image of the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Mmm.png)

**EDIT2:** [Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbE2H.png)

Comment: can you provide a screenshot from your document?

Comment: Sure! A screenshot is not added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.values(Stempletider).map((item) => console.log(item));
```

will help you in looping.

Comment: Thank you! Object.values() does not seem to work in typescript, as I get the error 'Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Tried

`Object.keys(oldTimestamps).map(key => console.log(oldTimestamps[key]));`

but it's not returning any values.

Comment: Hey I used the same thing in typescript it works for me

Comment: Sure! Added to the question under EDIT2.

Comment: I am not able to figure out why it is happening for you but in my case, it is allowing for using Object.values in typescript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are printing the data before pushing in into it? Is value changes Synchronous?

At least in Vanilla JS with firestore get() returns a promise so trying to access the data in the next line of code (not inside the Promise .then()) would return an empty object.

It seems like to get the desire result you would need to print that object inside your forEach or do something with the data there.

Comment: Hmm... I changes the code to `this.afd.collection<Items>('arbeidsokter').doc(this.planNext[0]["ID"])
      .valueChanges().subscribe((data) => oldTimestamps.push(data));
      
    console.log(oldTimestamps);` Now, an array is written to the console like in this screenshot [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXmpD.png), but `console.log(oldTimestamps[0])` still returns undefined.

Comment: And `console.log(oldTimestamps[0])` is also inside the foreach? I mean, does this work: `this.afd.collection<Items>('arbeidsokter').doc(this.planNext[0]["ID"]) .valueChanges().subscribe((data) => oldTimestamps.push(data)); console.log(oldTimestamps[0]);`

Comment: Sorry! Due to a short deadline, I had to prioritize other parts of the app. Will post here when I get time to look more into it :)